# iphone: change the name of .app file ( app executable )

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application on app store. suppose the executable name is X.app. now i want to send the update and i changed the executable name to Y.app

what happening is. when i update my new Y.app on device ( through Xcode ) that already has X.app installed. the splash screen comes and disappears and i am unable to start the application.

What is the solution to this problem. i really need to change the app name. Please suggest.

Comment: Hi guys, i have figured out. this problem is only occouring with XCode and debugging. through itunes i have installed the application with changed executable name. and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost no one sees the name of the executable or app bundle (unless one digs around in the iTunes Library directories).  You can change the name shown in the App store, and the name shown under the icon, without touching the name of the product, executable or app bundle.

One option is to edit the Bundle Display Name in your Info.plist, change the App Store's Application Name in iTunes Connect during the next update submission, change your website and marketing materials, and just leave the ProductName in Xcode unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

```
Go to target-> yourApplicationName(double click/get Info)->Build->ProductName
```

Set your new name for that application there

hAPPY cODING...